# Most intuitive way to parse several thousand different log types (with Python)?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, aws-lambda, bigdata

I'm interning at a small company this summer and have been tasked with parsing log files from a kinesis stream. This has an extremely high throughput, so I've been learning how to do 'real-time' parsing, for lack of a better term, so as to avoid bloating memory and incurring extra costs in lambda.

I went into the project expecting something tedious but manageable, but there are several problems I've encountered:

1. Delimiters are 'lost in translation' at some point between the logs being aggregated from many origins to when I receive them. There isn't anything I can easily do like break on tab, 4 spaces, 2 spaces, 3 spaces, colons, commas, etc. because it tends to fracture the logs at unintended points
2. There are apparently several thousand types of logs that need to be addressed and analyzed. Many of these are from the "same" source (MSWinEventLog, for example), but are still unique in their own right. Windows logs make up around ~85% of random samples. The spreadsheet of log types that was supplied to me records "0" instances of many types of logs, but I assume that their presence means they've been observed at some point outside that collection period.

Everytime I think I find a pattern in a particular type of log, one comes along from a different source and kills it. Field names for the most part are not included, outside of Windows event number specific data, which have colons attached

`heading1: field1: data1  field with spaces2: data2    field3: data3 with spaces     also_part_of_data3values field4: field5_after4_with_no_value: data5`

Right now my approach is somewhat naive and only addressed the Windows events. It employs a combination of regex and "smart pair" parsing. Regex to get some fields that I can somewhat rely on to be there, and to identify "key elements" when pairing. The pairing is for the parts that are delimited by colons (or '=' in the case of powershell logs). I make a good attempt at separating all fields and values into a list. Then, for each element, I check if it's a key. If it is, I pair it with the next element which *should* be a value. If the next element is also a key, then the last one is either a header or a field with no value, and is discarded. After pairing a key and value, if the next element does not match 'something:' pattern, then I assumed it's a key with multiple values. Once another key element is encountered the key: value(s) up to that point are added to a dictionary. So, from the above example I'd (hopefully) end up with:

```
"field1": "data1",
"field with spaces 2": "data2",
"field3": ["data3 with spaces", "also_part_of_data3values"],
"field5": "data5"
```

This approach sort of works for windows logs. I try and trim unnecessary information (for example, many logs include the description text from Windows about what an event is, that can be 10+ sentences).

My worry is that because the volume of logs is so huge it's really hard to account for every possible log that might go into the parser, especially with their formats not always being the same even within one log type (date / time I've noticed is extremely inconsistent in both order and delimiter). Writing a few thousand Regex doesn't seem practical for one person (me) to do either.

So I guess my question is: from people who have dealt with a similarly messy situation, how can I approach this and fix the duct-taped spaghetti I have now?

Comment: I think that this "job" will only be doable if you can find a way to determine the type/source of each log and use regexes or whatever other method you intended to use based on the type of log. Generate a uniform set of values that each regex for each log will return (for example one regex will return the field and corresponding data) and create regexes which do that for each type of log. Put them into an array, and load the specific regex pattern based on whichever type of log it is.

Comment: anytime you find something that doesnt match one of your expected cases put it into another file of "unknown" or something ... that way you can write a case for it ... and at least even if something un anticipated comes along in the future you are not losing data

Comment: Just to put my two cents in: one major problem will be to determine if this is a `field with spaces 2` or `also part of data3values` (both contain only one space). For starters, you could define a field as **word characters** + **only one space** and check if it is a field indeed with a callback function. To give you an idea: [**`((?:\w|\w\ \w)+):`**](https://regex101.com/r/oY1kN7/1)

Comment: Yet another version which takes the length and word boundaries into account: [**`\b((?:\w|\w\ \w){5,27}):`**](https://regex101.com/r/oY1kN7/2) - you'll need to play with several specifications here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

1. high frequency input
2. line delimited text
3. log schema of unknown semantics

   1. dominated by some
   2. long tail of rare "others"

I did in the past in python generator based processing in stages, which nicely scales. It does not automatically do machine learning at no cost, though.

So if the input is highly unspecified like described, but has a major core of known parts (85% of one defined species, as the OP states), then it helps to separate the "detection" clearly from the parsing.

Anything that does not fit a growing set of well-encapsulated rules is put in a "terra incognita" bucket to be inspected manually (maybe tagged with hints from a threshold detector).

The majority will be handed over to the matching parser and are fully processed.

Best would be, to have some stakeholders, giving allowance to a) finally skip or b) simply con cat the unknowns to a inspect me like log, for archiving or sampling or whatever.

If you are on your own, there seems to be no 100% working solution (which would in my understanding mean: "all parsed"), as more automation may lead to more false detected formats - errors will lower your result quality. Rare occurring schema instances may happen after you have "left the building" but I would not bet on that and personally would not suggest that attitude ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an answer only the following way:
Multi-tool that can do everything is not the solution, it's almost not possible to write a tool that can parse any logs, and provide to you a right info on a fly for any types of logs. **You have to maintain/support what you did.**

## TO DO PLAN:

**Plan A:**

1. Try to understand why and  what for you have been asked to parse
   logs: go to your colleagues/managers, set up meeting and figure out
   the real things that you need to do. And possibly reduce amount of logs for parsing.
2. Prepare the set of logs that
   you already have and try to figure out which of these logs are
   critical. Start from writing parsers for them.
3. Prepare base `class` for parsing logs with only basic functions (read, parse, save, etc)
4. Prepare classes with their own patterns and methods for parsing for know critical types of logs. Inherit from #3
5. Prepare class for `unmatched logs` that will save all new logs that were not parsed for future analysis. Inherit from #3
6. Do analysis for `unmatched logs` and repeat #4

If you have `extremely high throughput` as you said:
**Use `cache`** - There are not 0  probability that you have a lot of similar logs (For example if your app can not establish a connection you may have GB of absolutely the same logs) - try to save uniq parts of logs in cache, and compare with it.

**Plan B:**  I think for intern it may be a very good plan for summer:
Go deeper to [`Genetic programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) - it may help with generation new patterns for new logs (If you will do it please share you git hub link)